# How to change docker bridge address space (subnet)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having a problem with docker-compose. Currently, my stacks of containers are created in their own custom, isolated network, which is based on bridge. *E.g.* when running `docker-compose -p client1 up -d` it creates a network called `client1_default` which has subnet `172.18.0.9/16` which is a big subnet (`/16`).

I don't need such a big subnet, `/24` would be enough.

The problem is that with this current setup I'm limited to about ~25 stacks of containers because then docker (or libnetwork) runs out of address spaces to use. I'd be much better off with `/24` address spaces because then there would be much more available.

So the first question is: how can I make docker (and docker-compose) use `/24` subnet by default **without editing a the `docker-compose.yml` file**. I know this is possible, but it requires editing the .yml file for each client or creating an overriding .yml. This is suboptimal.

If this is not possible directly, I've scouted through the libnetwork code and found [this](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/eac8b773b4690bfbdfef9598dc95af6ae93a46df/ipamutils/utils.go) (there are a "Broad" and "Granular" address spaces, and by default it uses the "Broad"). How can I make docker use the Granular address space?
I read [here](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/docs/ipam.md#getdefaultaddressspaces) that

> For example, **if not specified otherwise in the configuration**, libnetwork will request address pool from the default local address space for a bridge network, whereas from the default global address space for an overlay network.

My question is then: how I can **specify it in the configuration**? What is the configuration mentioned? What is the syntax to change this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same problem where I need to have more control over the pool of Subnets that Docker-compose is using as its affecting my corp network.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BK8NcHUNF5M

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible, see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21776 + https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/29376
But you can take part in the discussion and vote.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using **flanneld** by CoreOS https://github.com/coreos/flannel
Then you can easily configure it by simple HTTP request to etcd. Additionally, you will get a single virtualised networks for all your containers (even running on different hosts). This may be useful if you decide to scale up in the future.

Comment: Thanks @andrey-chaussenko, I'll be looking into that. But I'm not sure I understand: what you meant by "you will get a single virtualised networks for all your containers". Fact is: I **need** to have the custom networks isolated for each client. This is the main reason I'm using docker-compose in the first place. Can I still have that?

Comment: @nachoe, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "isolated for each client". As far as I understand, you run group of containers together and want them to belong to the same virtual network. Do you have more then one such groups?

Comment: @andrey-chaussenko ah ok, we're not on the same page :-)  
Actually yes: I run groups of (2) containers that I want in their own private network. That's right. That currently works here.  
Problem is: this group of 2 containers gets a private network with /16 subnet, for only 2 containers!  
And yes I _definitely_ need more thant one group, actually I need about a hundred. And this is where my problem arises: I can't have 100 /16 subnet groups :/

Comment: @andrey-chaussenko I've setup `flanneld` but either it doesn't do what I need, either I misconfigured it. But all I could do with it is change my `docker0` interface's ip address. But it doesn't change anything on the subnet of the private networks :/